# How to keep one file extension and remove others?

Tags: shell, command-line

I have many file extension in directory: `.tr0`, `.scs`, `.mt0`, `.ic0`, `.log`, `.st0`, `.pa0`.

I want to keep just `.tr0` and `.scs` and delete all other extension.

Is there any effective way instead of:

```
rm *.mt0 *.ic0 *.log *.st0 *.pa0
```

Answer (score 2):

POSIXLY:

```
find . ! \( -name '*.tr0' -o -name '*.scs' \) -type f -exec echo rm -f {} +
```

(Remove `echo` when you want to execute command)

If your `find` support `-delete`:

```
find . ! \( -name '*.tr0' -o -name '*.scs' \) -type f -delete
```

---

The above command will work recursively. If you want in current directory only:

```
find . ! -name . -prune ! \( -name '*.tr0' -o -name '*.scs' \) -type f
```

Answer (score 2):

In a shell that allows for extended globbing patterns, such as `bash` with the `extglob` shell option enabled (`shopt -s extglob`) or `ksh93`:

```
rm ./*.!(tr0|scs)
```

The extended shell globbing pattern `!(pattern-list)` matches anything except the patterns specified in the `|`-delimited `pattern-list`.

---

Note that the pattern also matches directory names if they contain dots, but since `rm` does not by default remove directories, this would only result in a few error messages.

To work around this, one would use a loop, testing each matching name to make sure it refers to a regular file:

```
for name in ./*.!(tr0|scs); do
    [ -f "$name" ] && rm "$name"
done
```

Comment: Here you go, I went through the link you provided, it has good explanation about the problem with `ls` .
use `globs` instead of `ls`